# How to link dependencies with conflicting subdependency versions?

Tags: c++, dll, linker, clang, static-libraries

I'd like to link two libraries, `foo` and `bar`, into my dynamic library `mylib`. The issue is that `foo` depends on version A of `baz` and `bar` depends on version B of `baz`. I cannot link to both versions of `baz` without conflicting symbols. The versions of `baz` don't seem to be backwards-compatible either, so I can't simply clobber over with the newer version's symbols. `foo` and `bar` can be built either statically or dynamically.

More concretely, I'd like to link [librealsense](https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense) and the latest version (0.0.6) of [libuvc](https://github.com/ktossell/libuvc). However, librealsense has a heavily modified version of 0.0.5 of libuvc internally. That's why I can't simply swap out 0.0.5 for 0.0.6.

What is the right way of handling this situation?

Comment: I could codemod libuvc to avoid the conflicting symbols all together, but that seems hacky and there'd be no way of getting newer versions of libuvc without redoing that process.

Comment: Maybe helpful : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21783761/how-do-i-link-different-versions-of-the-same-library-in-g